# How can I change input styling when there's a value?

Tags: html, css

I have an input field and now I want to style it in a way so that whenever the input field is empty we need a normal border of black color and on focus need to change to red on filling.

```css
.form-control {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"} value={formValues.password} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```css
.form-control {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
 }
.form-control:hover,.form-control:focus {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"} value={formValues.password} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: how will you check if its empty?

Comment: for that you have to use javascript

Comment: Not really no :)